# Unwanted https redirect on subdomain with htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have some sub-domains `s1.mywebsite.com` and `s2.mywebsite.com`.  I'm trying to setup a URL rewrite rule to have any request intended for mywebsite.com be converted to https, while requests to the subdomain are unaltered.

Right now in the root of my main domain I have an htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://mywebsite.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

There's some content there for wordpress.  As it stands, my server rewrites the request `http://s1.mywebsite.com/page/` to `https://mywebsite.com/page/` completely obliterating the subdomain.  How can I have my rule ignore subdomain queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a condition to restrict first `https->http` rule for main domain only:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much!